A manga where the mc got summoned by orcs and has a cool ability
I'm trying to find a black and white isekai manga.
The first chapter shows the main character getting summoned by a group of orcs (to be eaten? I don't remember that much).
He defeated them with martial arts and gains skills; also I'm pretty sure he could speak Orc when they first met, which made the orcs confused.
He tried one of his skills which is like an air bullet in chapters ranging from 1 to 3. Another skill is that he can tame bees.

Just noting that saying “black and white manga” generally isn’t needed - “Manga is traditionally illustrated in black and white and flaunts stylized, dramatic-looking characters. Both manhua and manhwa are illustrated in full color and depict characters in a more realistic manner.” according to a web search of “manhua black and white”

Might it be Isekai Shihai no Skill Taker: Zero kara Hajimeru Dorei Harem? This Reddit post states he was summoned by orcs and steals their skills. I can't confirm it right now though.


Konoe Yuuto is a genius martial artist who is summoned to a different world where slave trading is legal. There, using his "Skill Taker" cheat ability, he steals the abilities of monsters he defeats, and starts building a slave harem while hoping to live a carefree life after retirement.

Found with a search for manga isekai summoned by orcs

In retrospect, I saw https://www.reddit.com/r/Isekai/comments/hmywqr/looking_for_a_particular_manga_i_read_before/ earlier, but it hadn't loaded the comments, so I thought no answer had been provided.
